# 98 jeep cherokee rear hatch latch bolt size?

Tags: jeep, cherokee

[image: rear hatch latch] I have a 98 Jeep Cherokee and the rear hatch latch is missing the bolts that hold it in place.the rear end still closes and latches, but without the bolts it rattles and the sensor says it is not closed. Does anyone know the size, length, or anything about these bolts??? Are they fine threaded? And any idea where I can pick some up?? I have tried a few different sizes but believe that it is a fine tread.

[image: bolt holes]

Comment: To post pictures, click the picture icon just above the text area you are writing in. It is the sixth icon from the left ... or conversely, press <Ctrl>+<g> and the dialog box will appear.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to figure this out is to go down to the Chrysler/Jeep dealer's parts shop and have them look it up for you. Describe them exactly what you are looking for and they will have a computer screen to match the part for you. I wouldn't buy the part there, because the "stealership" will charge you an exorbitant amount of money for each bolt (probably along the lines of 5x what you'd buy something comparable from Lowe's/Home Depot ... something which may not be exact, but will work). Another thought is to go to a pick-a-part yard or any junkyard for that matter. Tell them exactly what you need and they'll sell it to you cheap, probably in the $2-3 for a the exact bolts, just used.

Answer (score 0):

8m-1.25x 23mm long pan head.  I got that info from the local dealer and I was able to go to my local hardware store and get one close enough. They didn't have 23mm so I bought a 20 and 25 to see which one worked better.  Each were $1.20. They had Alan and Phillips heads. I bought the Alan. I wasn't sure how much pressure I'd have to use and didn't want to strip out the philips. In the end the 20mm bolts works great.